# How can I use site field in an email template?

Tags: force.com-sites, email-template, merge-field

I'm trying to add *Site Fields* into my *Email Template*, but in the mail these fields are blank. I tried adding this into my *Email Template*:

```
<br/>tld: {!Site.TopLevelDomain}
<br/>upp: {!Site.UrlPathPrefix}
<br/>id: {!Site.Id}
<br/>ml: {!Site.MasterLabel}
<br/>name: {!Site.Name}
<br/>sd: {!Site.Subdomain}
```

But after clicking *Send Test and Verify Merge Fields* and getting the mail I only see this in the mail:

> tld:
>
> upp:
>
> id:
>
> ml:
>
> name:
>
> sd:

I need to include the site address in the mail so that users will be able to go to a public page in the site. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the dollar sign in your Site-variables, please replace your code with:

```
<br/>tld: {!$Site.TopLevelDomain}
<br/>upp: {!$Site.UrlPathPrefix}
<br/>id: {!$Site.Id}
<br/>ml: {!$Site.MasterLabel}
<br/>name: {!$Site.Name}
<br/>sd: {!$Site.Subdomain}
```

Remember that all global variables are referenced with a dollar sign.